# In email the data is coming in the next line which looks weird

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

`

```
const mailOptions = {
        from: 'me@me.com>',
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Welcome User',
        html:'<h1><b>Hey, </b></h1>' + req.body.name + '<br><h1>Welcome to the Club</h1> <br> <h2> Your Password:</h2>' + req.body.pw + '<h3><em> Star this mail so if you forget your password this email would help you</em></h3>'
      };
```

`

The data of req.body.name and pw is going in the next lines in email which starts to looks weird.

I want to have the req.body.pw and name in the same line in output/email.

Comment: The `</h1>` ends the heading and starts a new line, try `<h1><b>Hey, </b>' + req.body.name + ' </h1>' ` instead.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thankyou so much :) <3 it worked for me. Thankyou so much sir <3